# print something if captcha is displayed on the page

Tags: python, captcha

I would like to add a captcha check on my script. I'm trying to do it like this but it doesn't work:

```
capt = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='rc-imageselect']")

if capt :
    print("captcha")
else:
    print ("no captcha")
```

I searched but I didn't find any way to fix this. It prints "no captcha" even if the page has captcha displayed. How to fix this? I need just to check if the captcha is displayed then print something. Can you please help me to fix this?

Comment: would it be possible to share web app URL?

Comment: Also, are you trying to verify captcha box there or captcha text is displayed?